# Question on convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, the medians of the triangle $ABC$ intersect at point $M$, and the medians of
the triangle $ACD$ intersect at point $N$. The circle circumscribed around the triangle $ACM$ intersects the segment $BD$ at the
point $K$, lying inside the triangle $AMB$. It is known that $\angle\, MAN = \angle \, ANC = 90^{\circ}$.
Prove that $\angle \, AKD = \angle \, MKC$.

Comment: Perhaps one way that you can show some evidence of work attempted would be to include a labelled diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $c$ the circle circumscribed around thriangle $\Delta \,ACM$ and denote by $E$ the second intersection point of the line $CN$ with the circle $c$, the first being point $C$. Furthermore, denote by $P, \, Q,\, R$ the midpoints of the segment $CA, \, AE, \, EC$ respectively. By construction, the triangle $\Delta\, ACE$ is inscribed in the circle $c$ and the segments $AR, \, CQ, \, EP$ are the three medians of $\Delta\, ACE$, so they intersect in a common point, we denote by $G\,$ (i.e. $G$ is the centroid of $\Delta\, ACE$).

By the properties of the common intersection point $G$ of the three medians $AR, \, CQ, \, EP$ of the triangle $\Delta\, ACE$,  the circumcircle $c_0$ of the midpoint triangle $\Delta \, PQR$ is the six point circle (also known as the nine point circle) of $\Delta \, ACE$ and as such passes through the feet of the three altitudes of triangle $\Delta \, ACE$. In particular it passes through the point $N$, because $\angle \, ANC = 90^{\circ}$ which means that $N$ is the foot of the altitude $AN$ of $\Delta \, ACE$. Alternatively, you can justify this latter fact by either arguing that triangles $PQR$ and $PQN$ are congruent, or by noticing that $\angle \, PRQ = \angle \, PAQ = \angle \, PNQ$, which means that $N$ lies on the circle $c_0$ circumscribed around the triangle $\Delta \, PQR$.

Consider the homothetic transformation with center $G$ and scaling factor $-\, 2$. Then, the triangle $\Delta \, ACE$ is the homothetic image of $\Delta \, PQR$ with respect to the said homothety. Consequently, the circumcircle $c_0$ of $\Delta\, PQR$ is mapped to the circumcircle of $\Delta\, ACE$. Furthermore, point $R$ is mapped to point $A$. Thus, the line $RN \equiv CE$ is mapped by the homothety to the unique line parallel to line $RN \equiv CE$, passing through the point $A$. However, by assumption, $\angle \, MAN = \angle\, ANC = 90^{\circ}$, which means that $AM \,\, || \,\, RN$, so $AM$ is the homothetic image of the line $RN$. Moreover, point $N$ is a point of intersection of the line $RN$ with the circle $c_0$, so its image under the homothety is a point of intersection of the line $AM$ with the circle $c$. This latter point is point $M$, because the other intersection point of $AM \cap c$ is point $A$, which is the image of point $R$. Therefore, the three point $M, \, N,\, G$ are collinear and 
$\frac{GP}{GE} = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{GN}{GM}$.

Perform another homothety, this time with center $P$ and scaling factor $3$. Since the three points $M, \, N, \, G$ are the centroids of the three triangles $\Delta \, ABC, \, \Delta \, ACD, \, \Delta \, ACN$ respectively, for the corresponding medians $PB, \, PD,\, PE$ the following ratio identities hold:
$$\frac{PB}{PM} = \frac{PD}{PN} = \frac{PG}{PE} = 3$$ which means that the three points $M, \, N, \, G$ are mapped by the homothety to the points $B, \, D, \, E$ respectively. However, we have already proved that the three points $M, \, N, \, G$ are collinear, which means that their homothetic images $B, \, D, \, E$ are also collinear.

Finally, by assumption, the quadrilateral $AMCE$ is inscribed in the circle $c$ and since $AM \,\, || \,\, EC$, the quadrilateral $AMCE$ is a trapezoid inscribed in a circle, so it is an isosceles trapezoid with $AE = MC$. Consequently, for the corresponding (smaller) arcs, we have $\text{arc}(AE) = \text{arc}(MC)$. Recall that point $K$ is the other intersection point of $BD$ with the circle $c$, the first one being $E$. By the properties of peripheral angles inscribed in a circle,
$$\angle \, AKE = \text{arc}(AE) = \text{arc}(MC) = \angle \, MKC$$
By the fact that $E$ lies on the segment $BD$, we conclude that 
$$\angle \, AKD = \angle \, AKE = \angle \, MKC$$